# iTextsharp - XmlWorker PDF - &#160 visible in PDF

Tags: c#, itext, xmlworker

I am converting HTML to PDF using iTextSharp XMLWorkder class. Everything working fine except when there is any empty HTML table is there, it puts `"&#160;"` character in that, which is then visible in PDF clearly.

I tried to replace this with empty space or `<br/>`, but it gave error "table width must be greater than zero".

Can any one suggest what should I do?

Comment: Just to be clear, `&#160;` is an HTML thing, not a PDF thing. Are you literally seeing those 6 characters printed or are you see a giant blank space? Also, what is an empty table? `<table />` or `<table></table>` or `<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>` or something similar?

Comment: @ChrisHaas - `<table />` and `<table></table>` throw a `System.ArgumentException`. `<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>` works, but does **not** put `&#160;` in the PDF. In fact, a quick global search of the `XMLWorker` source code (5.5.8) does not find `&#160;`, so probably something else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doubt `iTextSharp` puts `&#160;` in the PDF. On the contrary, `iTextSharp` is smart enough to correctly recognize it as a non breaking space. Here's proof:

```
    string HTML = @"
<div>
<h1>HTML Encoded non breaking space</h1><table border='1'><tr><td>&amp;#160;</td></tr></table>
<h1>HTML non breaking space</h1><table border='1'><tr><td>&#160;</td></tr></table>
<div style='background-color:yellow;'><h1>Empty Table</h1><table><tr><td></td></tr></table></div>
</div>
    ";

using (var stringReader = new StringReader(HTML))
{
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(
        outputFile,
        FileMode.Create,
        FileAccess.Write))
    {
        using (var document = new Document())
        {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(
                document, stream
            );
            document.Open();
            XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(
                writer, document, stringReader
            );
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

So the more likely case is that the `HTML` sent to the parser has encoded `&#160;` as `&amp;#160;`. The simple fix is to *replace* the encoded HTML entity **before** it goes to the parser:

```
HTML = HTML.Replace("&amp;#160;", "\u00A0");
```